# How to show that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is not a $\mathbb Q-$module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

How to show that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is not a $\mathbb Q-$module ? I tried to define an action $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\longrightarrow \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ but I can't conclude.

Comment: Can a $\mathbb{Q}$-module have torsion? Does $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ have torsion?

Comment: If R is a commutative domain and Q is its field of fractions, then Q/R is a torsion R-module.

Comment: Incidentally, $\mathbf Q$-module is usually called a  $\mathbf Q$-vector space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose there would be some way to define a $\mathbb{Q}$-module structure on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, denote it by "$\cdot$". Then, for example:

$$2\cdot (\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z}) = (1+1)\cdot (\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z}) = 
(\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z})+(\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z} = 0_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} }  $$
But on the other hand:
$$\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z}=(\frac{1}{2}.2)(\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z} )=\frac{1}{2} \cdot ( 2 \cdot (\frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{Z})) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}    $$
Obviously a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose $Q/Z$ is a unitary $Q$- modulr. Let $Q/Z$ be a $Q$-module, since $Q$ is a field, so $Q/Z$ is a vector space. Let $a/b+Z$ be an element of a basis, but we have $b.(a/b+Z)=0$$(a, b \in Z)$, a contradiction. If we omit the unitary assumption the zero product is an example for required product.